# Bind data to combobox

Tags: c#, data-binding, .net-4.0, combobox

In this Load function have some hotel names,I wanted to bind that hotel names to Combo box. I go several steps but i'm having a problem in bind values to combo box from here.

```
private void myWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string new1 = f.Name; //hotel names comes here(eg:hilton,serandib)

    List<string> Hotels = new1 List<string>();
    Hotels.Add(new1);
    foreach (string Hotel in Hotels)
    {

    }
 }
```

Actually i want this hotel names show in combo box.(This is a windows form),Help me with the rest.

Comment: What is the error ? i think new is reserved keyword and you can not use it as a variable name!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768328/c-sharp-combobox-binding-to-list-of-objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of following code,

```
ComboBox1.DataSource = hotelList;
```

if you have following string coming from `f.Name`

"Le meridian, Fortune, Asiana"

```
    List<String> hotelList = f.Name.Split(',').ToList();

    ComboBox1.DataSource = hotelList;
```

Comment: Just collect all the names in a list and bind it..as mentioned!

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Hotels> Hname = new List<Hotels> { "Taj", " Star", "Poorna" ,"Settinad" };
comboBox.DataSource =  Hname;
```

or

```
List<Hotels> Hotel = new List<Hotels>();
Hotel.Add( "name");

comboBox.DataSource = Hotel;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        List<string> names = new List<string>();
        names.Add("name1");
        names.Add("name2");
        names.Add("name3");
        names.Add("name4");
        names.Add("name5");
        comboBox1.Items.Clear();
        foreach (string name in names)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(name);
        }
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0; //selects first item
```

Answer (score 1):

You're about to add a items to `ComboBox` but actually you don't need use the `List<string>` to list the items to `ComboBox`, you can go it directly in `.Items` of `ComboBox`

```
 string new1 = f.Name; //hotel names comes here(eg:hilton,serandib)
 comboBox5.Items.Add(new1);
```